# Smalltalk dynamic lookup optimization

Tags: smalltalk, dynamic-dispatch

In Smalltalk, looking up a method at run time can involve a large number of steps, since the method dictionary of a subclass does not contain methods in its superclass, and a pointer-chase is required to find the method. A optimization would be for each subclass to store all superclass methods in its method dictionary.
Question: How could this be done?

An obvious drawback is the space cost, but I'm just wondering how this can be done in Smalltalk? This is different from making a separate cache for recently invoked methods.

Comment: Just to point out, the space cost wouldn't be the only drawback. Imagine you want to refactor a class to now have a different superclass... eww. Plus, you'd have to store not only the superclass methods, but also their location in the hierarchy, so that you could properly determine which one is "closest" to the calling class. The "large number of steps" you mention are not, in my opinion, so inefficient that this needs to be re-considered. What benefit are you looking for?

Answer (score 5):

There are so many ways to cache the results of a lookup. Just read some basic VMimplementation papers - start with the Green Book. You can even find t for free online - http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks.html and look near the bottom for 'Bits of History, Words of Advice'.
Plain interpreters can use a simple hash keyed cache. Translating VMs can get into inline caches, polymorphic inline caches, adaptive caching... no need whatsoever to d something as painful as C++ vtables which is pretty much what you were suggesting.
We've had this covered for decades. It's solved.

Answer (score 4):

> In Smalltalk, looking up a method at run time can involve a large number of steps, since the method dictionary of a subclass does not contain methods in its superclass

This would be true for interpreted Smalltalk that doesn't attempt to do any optimizations, Many Smalltalks (e.g. Pharo) are actually compiled and there's a lot of optimizations in the virtual machine… so message lookup is certainly not something that I would be worried about performance-wise.

As for the so-called class flattening… the naive way is actually pretty trivial, you just copy all the parent methods

```
Child withAllSuperclassesDo: [ :cls |
    cls methods do: [ :m |
        (Child selectors includes: m selector) ifFalse: [ 
            Child compile: m sourceCode classified: m protocol
        ]
    ]
]
```

and sure enough all the methods are there

[image]

You probably wouldn't want to copy the complete hierarchy but you can easily limit it to e.g. a package, or a couple of ancestors.

### What about `super`?

There might be a not-so-nice catch with `super`, which relies on being in a specific place in the hierarchy. If you for example override certain method and call method in the parent that uses `super`… and then you flatten it… you might end up in an endless loop, or worse.

So you would probably need to analyze the source code if all such references are correct… and I am not sure this can be done automatically, because it might depend on the logic of the code, which you have to analyze with your own eyes and mind. This also means that you cannot blindly copy all the methods or point to the same method from multiple classes, because `super` takes on different meanings.

And as Amos aptly pointed out… this is unrefactorable.

**Update** to answer @aka.nice's comment (and further demonstrate why `super` is problematic)

[image]
[image]

On the left before flattening, on the right after.

Pretty much anytime the method containing super does something (as it should), you are basically invoking the behavior at least twice.

Comment: My +1 just for the use of "unrefactorable" ;-)

Comment: For super, it would be easy if `super a` would be invoked only from method `a`: then we just would not import the methods than send to super... But not all methods are well behaved, we sometimes see `super a` from method `b` which then forbid importing methods that are sent to super, not only methods that send to super... Still doable.

Comment: @Peter but you wouldn't import a precisely because some superclass sends super a. That does not contradict me...

Answer (score 2):

Some dialects use another technique to minimize the number of operations required to enumerate the chain of `MethodDictionaries`: the so called `MDA` or Method Dictionary Array.

The idea is for the class to keep an array containing the `MD` of its instances in the first slot, then the `MD` of its superclass, and so on.

A nice thing about this technique is that it can be implemented at the instance level. Instead of storing the class in object headers, one can store the `MDA` of the class. This is 100% compatible with the class-check that happens in method sends, except that it becomes an `MDA`-check instead.

Moreover, if you reify the `MDA` you can add behavior to it so to make it support nesting. In this way, the outer array may contain `MDs` or nested `MDA`. Nesting can be used to add instance-specific behavior without detaching from the `MDA` of the class: put the instance-specific behavior in a `MD` and store it in slot 1 and then put the `MDA` of the class in slot 2. If the `MDA` of the class changes, the instance will not have to do anything special to attach to the modified `MDA`. (Had the instance created its own `MDA` with its `MD` in slot 1 and the class `MDs` in subsequent slots, the `MDA` of the class would have been detached from the instance one)

BTW, the cost in space is small because there is nothing duplicated.